# How to avoid stiffness and crispness of toasted/oven baked bread sandwiches

Tags: baking, bread, sandwich

I would like to know whether there is any solution to avoid the stiffness and crispness of bread of oven baked sandwiches which uses normal white bread as the base. I used to make sandwiches with bread and always these bread after baking turns out really crispy and stiff and sometimes it get burnt. I butter the bread sometimes and sometimes not. Either way I end up with crispy bread sandwich which is difficult to bite and affects our mouth skin. How can we make the bread base of the sandwich soft?

Comment: Isn't that like trying to make dry water? I sort of assumed that crispyness would be the reason for baking the sandwiches?

Comment: "always these bread after baking turns out really crispy and stiff and sometimes it get burnt" - that'll be the baking. Why are you baking your sandwiches anyway?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the sandwich in foil before baking so the moisture stays in the bread. That will prevent it crisping up.

Comment: And use aluminum, not plastic... ^_^.

Comment: If it was plastic, it wouldn't be foil, it would be film. :P

Comment: Ok.. Thanks @ElendilTheTall. Actually I tried using the foil and butter-paper below the sandwich but I did'nt think of wrapping it.

Comment: In honour of a certain college student I know (and probably thousands of others) I felt obliged to point out the difference - before another sandwich gets shrink-wrapped and the kitchen filled with smoke.

Answer (score 6):

The bread gets crispy and "stiff" because it dries up completely.

A good toaster should toast a slice of bread quickly so that the exterior is toasted and the interior barely hot; a bad toaster will not be warm enough and will dry up the slice of bread.

Same thing when you do an oven baked sandwich, it should be done on high heat so that the bread toasts up and crisps up on the exterior while not drying up the bread.

Answer (score 0):

You say "toasted" in your title but there are various ways to achieve this, different ines dominating in different countries.  If you have a slot toaster (common in the UK, much less so in the rest of Europe, and apparently common in the US/Canada) there are [toastabags](http://www.lakeland.co.uk/10724/Lakeland-Toastabag-500) (although this link is lakeland, they're on e.g. amazon as well).  These are reusable bags made of non-stick sheet, open on one edge.  You make the sandwich, put it in, than stuff it into the toaster. I tend to give the sandwich 20 seconds in the microwave before toasting to make sure the cheese is nicely melted.

Alternatively if your oven has a grill setting that will work a lot better than oven mode.

Comment: For my own curiosity: If slot toasters are uncommon in the USA, what is commonly used to toast sliced bread?

Comment: A quick look suggests that slow toasters are more commmon than I thought -- Walmart sell quite a few models online -- but toaster ovens seem more common to me.  I'm thinking of motels with kitchenettes though.  A toaster oven, from a Brisitsh point of view, is a small electric grill with a door. [Pics (Walmart)](http://www.walmart.com/browse/home/toasters-ovens/4044_90548_90546_90774).

Comment: Almost every household has a "slot toaster" here in the US. We just call them "toasters."

Comment: If you say "toaster" to someone in Canada, by default they think of a metal box with two slots in the top and a lever on the front.  We do have toaster ovens, but they are called "toaster ovens".

Comment: @James, edited, and -- bonus -- that mean you can use toastabags, which IMO give a nicer result than a sandwich toaster/toastie maker.  They also don't take up any real kitchen space.

Comment: what makes you think toasters are uncommon in the rest of Europe? At least for Germany I strongly disagree - a toaster and a water cooker were my first electrical kitchen appliances.

Comment: @Stephie I've found them to be universal in holiday rentals in Britain, and uncommon in France. The family homes I stayed in (in both France and Germany) lacked toasters but that was 20 years ago.

Comment: @ChrisH - uncommon in holiday rentals perhaps, but not in "everyday" households? Watever...

Comment: @Stephie, that's the point I was trying to make -- comparing holiday rental across countries seemed to only give a partial picture.